# Provably secure and Practical ciphers

Tags: encryption, cryptanalysis, block-cipher, algorithm-design, provable-security

Are there any  ciphers that are

1. provably secure (reducable to a hard problem (including like factorization, not necessarily to NP-Complete or harder) )
2. are practical (not necessarily for too much bulk action like videos, but for small text messages, by humans) with decent security ~ 2^100

notes:

- blum-blum shub seems to be way too slow
- DUAL_EC_DRBG seems to have a proof, (was probably nsa backdoored, but versions with random values for constants seems good enough), does anyone know about it's practical performance, for even small text chat application (also i don;t find it's implementation in any standard library)
- are there any more

Comment: If you want a symmetric key encryption scheme with a security reduction to a hard problem then you can simply take any good public key encryption scheme and use the public/private key pair as the symmetric key. If you're going for post quantum schemes, then lattice based schemes will have no problem encrypting short messages.

Comment: Doesn't RSA-OAEP have a security proof (twice adjusted?). It's not quantum secure, but it would take a lot of qbits, and yes, it *exactly* maps to the prime factorization problem. Or does it rely too much on MGF1 for that?

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Doesn't RSA-OAEP have a security proof .... dosen't seem so, Whether it is as difficult as the factoring problem is an open question  from wikipedia [1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(cryptosystem)) and Indeed, there is strong evidence pointing to this conclusion: that a method to break the RSA method cannot be converted necessarily into a method for factoring large semiprimes.  [2] (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_problem)

Comment: @lamba like which scheme, which is provably reducible to a hard problem

Comment: You can take Kyber that was selected by NIST. It's designed as a KEM but you can make it into a PKE. It has a security reduction to the LWE problem.

Comment: @lamba thanx, that seems to be the case, after your first post i also looked into lattice based schemes, some of them (ring-LWE) do reduce to  NP-hard problem, it is not 100percent clear to me that kyber in particular does that (iam not very familiar with laticce), but since it won the nist it will likely become the standard, and will be implemented in openssl soon etc. , as of now there are only 'experimental' implementations.  nrtu etc however don;t seem to reduce, but in lattice based system there are potentially many which reduce to an actual NP-hard problem.. thanx for pointing me to that